# Linux-Filesystem without birth-timestamp

Tags: linux, filesystems, timestamp

More and more linux-filesystems not only support known **a**ccess and **m**odify-timestamps, but also **b**irth-timestamps. Examples are ext4 and newer xfs-versions.

These birth-timestamps describe when a file was originally created and can usually not be changed by the user, which is fine for the usual usecase of this timestamp.

We however run a system storing sensitive information, where (exact) creation timestamps could be used to deduct part of the content. For that reason, we modify access and modify-timestamps using `touch` stripping too accurate parts of these timestamps, essentially running modulo 6h on them.

However, running stat on these files the new birth-timestamps can be seen with quite exact timestamps. I did some research for ext4 and xfs if it would be possible to ignore birth-timestamps and write 0 for all of them, but sadly I could not find such mount-option.

Using disk-encryption is not an option for us, as the encryption key must be recalculated for each file and encryption must happen inside of our application. So currently aes256-encrypted zip-files serve the purpouse quite well, except for the birth-timestamps.

Comment: After creating the file, queue up something like `sleep $(( RANDOM % 21600 )); mv file oldfile; cp oldfile file; rm -f oldfile`?

Comment: Which time is written to the file? System time? Can you randomly change the system time before writing and recover it after?

Comment: EXT4 supports filesystem encryption per directories, maybe this is an alternative to encrypted zip-files for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

larsks: That would be one way, I hoped there would be another way without re-writing the content to the filesystem.

MaestroGlanz: yes it is system-time, but changing system time for this task seems to be a large one of a hammer which will possibly come with enough side-effects.

paladin: As far as I understand https://lwn.net/Articles/639427, the inode of the files won't be encrypted, only file contents. So while this would be an alternative to encrypted zip-files, the original problem would still be there.